# Getting error in installing scala

Tags: java, scala, sbt

i follow the tutorial https://class.coursera.org/progfun-005/lecture/21
to install Scala.
I have already java install in it.As the tutorial guides i download the latest sbt and install  it.
But when i am trying to run in command prompt by  typing

> sbt sbtVersion  it gives an error that "Files was unexpected at this time"
>      I am new in this so ignore if i am making any silly error

Answer (score 1):

[Download the jar](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html) and run it using `java -jar /location/of/the/downloaded/jar/from/the/previous/link` -- leave a comment if you have further problems.

Comment: i followed your step but it leads me nowhere .it shows me something like this >   i dont know what to type after >